# PHP code formatter with Drupal coding style

Tags: php, drupal

We do our Drupal programming mostly with simple text editors like Vim. Now, after several years of development and many different people working on the project, the coding conventions have diverged a bit :-)

Drupal itself has a clear code style and a script exists to identify violations of the coding conventions. However, fixing everything by hand is too much effort and could possibly introduce errors.

I wonder if there is any customizable non-commercial PHP code formatter, which can process all PHP files of a project in a batch run. [I only found a closed solution](http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/), which doesn't seem to be customizable.

Comment: Totally unclear to me why it is "not constructive" to ask for a free PHP code formatter to be runable in a batch mode?

Answer (score 0):

As for Drupal, we have [Coder](http://drupal.org/project/coder) module.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fullfil my requirement of running the code fixing on a tree of source files in a batch. I think the Coder module is very useful for Drupal development, but I don't see how to use that in a custom development project based on Drupal.

Comment: Coder can evaluate and alter files. It doesn't do PHP 5.3+ syntax well though... **edit** Right, but per module and not a tree... You can hack Coder though =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try our [PHP Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/PHPFormatter.html).

It is scriptable, and using a project file, it can 
be run on as large a batch of PHP files as one desires.

Because it uses a language accurate parser and prettyprinter, it will not break your code when reformatting.

I don't know if has a "Drupal" style, but it has some configurability.

(This seemed pretty easy to find with Google using "PHP Formatter").

Comment: Ok, I should have stated more clearly that I was looking for an open solution :-/